# Saved video preferred transform is showing landscape for portrait videos

Tags: ios, video, gpuimage

i am using GPUImage movie framework to do save a portrait video. Even the video which is saved in the album is in portrait mode with a resolution of 720*1240 but in the code when i am checking the preferred transform of that video it is showing landscape . Following are the respective code

```
filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
filterView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill;
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack ];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
videoCamera.shouldSmoothlyScaleOutput=YES;
videoCamera.frameRate = 30.0;
movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(720, 1280)];
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[filter removeAllTargets]; 
filter = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];
[filter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(720, 1280)];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];


[filter addTarget:filterView];
 [filter addTarget:movieWriter];
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieWriter startRecording];
```

then when the recording is done i stop the moviewriter and save it in camera roll. After that when i take that video from camera roll to edit, i first check it's orientation and there i find out that it is in landscape , the code for that part is below

```
AVURLAsset *assetClip = VD.assetForVideoMemory ;
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[assetClip tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
CGSize size = [clipVideoTrack naturalSize];
    CGAffineTransform rotation;
    CGAffineTransform txf = [clipVideoTrack preferredTransform];
    CGAffineTransform translateToCenter;
    CGAffineTransform mixedTransform;
    float scaleFX = 0, scaleFY =0;
    CGSize naturalSize;
    CGAffineTransform scaleXY;

// changing the height and width of the video
    if (txf.a == 0 && txf.b == 1.0 && txf.c == -1.0 && txf.d == 0)// portrait
    {
        naturalSize = CGSizeMake(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width);
    }
    if (txf.a == 0 && txf.b == -1.0 && txf.c == 1.0 && txf.d == 0)// portrait upside down
    {
        naturalSize = CGSizeMake(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width);
    }
    if (txf.a == 1.0 && txf.b == 0 && txf.c == 0 && txf.d == 1.0) // landscape left
    {
        naturalSize = CGSizeMake(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height);
    }
    if (txf.a == -1.0 && txf.b == 0 && txf.c == 0 && txf.d == -1.0)// landscape right
    {
        naturalSize = CGSizeMake(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height);
    }
```

now in the above code it is always showing that the video is in landscape left , even for the portrait . Where is the problem ?? why it is not giving  the portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

I found that if video is written using AVFileTypeAppleM4V preset, the preferredOrientation, which AVAssetTrack then reads, is incorrect. However, when writing with AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie preset, AVAssetTrack gets the same orientation that was specified during write. Also Iphone Camera app seems to write with that latter preset.

My guess is that you are writing using AVFileTypeAppleM4V.